# In Telethon: How can I verify If ChatAction was only from my group/channel, when I am not sure If my group/channel is private or public?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

For now, I am assuming e.chat takes a specific URL of my group/channel either it's public or private and works as a filter and If any event like a user joined or left in my group/channel, it will print in the console.

```
@bot.on(events.ChatAction(func=lambda e: not e.is_private and e.chat == "https://t.me/123"))
async def imp_fun(event):
    print(event.user_joined)

    print(event.user_left)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `chats=` filter:

```py
@bot.on(events.ChatAction(chats=[-100123456, 'username', ...]))
async def imp_fun(event):
    ...
```